# how to execute bulk insert statement in java (using JDBC) with db=SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-express

I am trying to execute a BULK INSERT statement on SQL Server 2008 Express.
(It basically takes all fields in a specified file and inserts these fields into appropriate columns in a table.)

Given below is an example of the bulk insert statement--

```
BULK INSERT SalesHistory FROM 'c:\SalesHistoryText.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

Given below is the Java code I am trying to use (but its not working)...Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here or point me to a java code sample/tutorial that uses the Bulk Insert statement? --

```
public void insertdata(String filename)
{
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String createString = "BULK INSERT Assignors FROM  " + path + "\\" +filename+ ".txt WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')";   
    try  
       { 
            // Load the SQLServerDriver class, build the 
            // connection string, and get a connection 
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://arvind-pc\\sqlexpress;" + 
                                    "database=test01;" + 
                                    "user=sa;" + 
                                    "password=password1983"; 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
            System.out.println("Connected."); 

            // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.  
            String SQL = "BULK INSERT dbo.Assignor FROM  " + path + "\\" +filename+ ".txt WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')";  
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

            // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.  
            while (rs.next())  
            {  
               //System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println(" Going through data");
            }

       }  
       catch(Exception e)  
       { 
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
            System.exit(0);  
       } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'its not working'?  What should be happening but isn't?  What error message (if any) are you getting?

Comment: @LukeWoodward- The surprising thing is, I am not getting any kind of message (of success or error)... I have put some messages to be output to console upon successful connection, as well as looping through resultset after execution of the statement... The entire block of code has a try..catch in which the error message is printed onto console... But no message is being shown..??!!

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess that your SQL string is missing the single quotes around the filename.  Try the following:

```
        String SQL = "BULK INSERT dbo.Assignor FROM '" + path + "\\" +filename+ ".txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')";
```

**EDIT** in response to your comment:  I wouldn't expect there to be anything in the ResultSet following a bulk insert, in much the same way that I wouldn't expect anything in a ResultSet following an ordinary `INSERT` statement.  These statements just insert the data they are given into a table, they don't return it as well.

If you're not getting any error message, then it looks like your bulk insert is working.  If you query the table in SQLCMD or SQL Server Management Studio, do you see the data?

`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `BULK INSERT` statements are not queries, so you shouldn't be using them with the `executeQuery()` method.  `executeQuery()` is only intended for running `SELECT` queries.  I recommend using the [`executeUpdate(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) method instead.  This method returns an `int`, which is normally the number of rows inserted/updated/deleted.