# How to insert data from a text file from Java to SQL server?

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

I made this source code to try to insert data from a text file but it does not do what I want.

First I declare variables with assigned values to insert as default values to my table and then just take the new values entered through the text file. I do not know the correct insert I should use.

```
package Clases;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;
public class Importar  {

    public static Connection Conexión;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);

            String ID_Origin = "NE001";
            short siPeriod = 2015;
            byte TypeTrans = 0;
            String ID_Entry = "";
            short siType = 0;
            String Concept = "";
            String ID_Class = "01"; 
            String ID_Budget = null;
            java.sql.Timestamp dtDate = null; 
            String ID_Cost = null;
            java.math.BigDecimal Debits = null;
            java.math.BigDecimal Credits = null;
            String ID_Currency = null;
            BigDecimal AmountFOB = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            BigDecimal CurrencyRate = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            boolean boCashFlow = false;
            short Status = 0;
            short StatusConsol = 0;
            System.out.println("ID_Entry");
            ID_Entry = lector.next();
            System.out.println("Concept");
            Concept = lector.next();
            System.out.println("dtDate");
            System.out.println("Debits");
            System.out.println("Credits");
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Conexión = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:sqlserver://SSL2541\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;" +
                "databaseName=namedatabase;user=sa;password=password");
            PreparedStatement enrollItmt;
            // This is where I have my confusion and did not return
            // anything the program   
            enrollItmt = Conexión.prepareStatement(
                "LOAD FROM 'C://Users//aurbina//Desktop//cargadatabase.txt' "
              + "INSERT INTO tablename( ID_Entry, siType, Concept, ID_Class, "
              + "dtDate, Debits, Credits)"
              + "VALUES (+Concept, +dtDate, +Debits, +Credits)");
            enrollItmt.execute();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achive? What doen't work?

Comment: for large text files try `mysqlimport` or Oracle equivalent `sqlldr`

Comment: @Palcente "SQL-Server 2012"...

Comment: It is for these data that I have in the txt file can be inserted into the table and columns that I assigned, since I also having values that are entered by default through the variables that I stated, there are some fields you should always have the same data.

Comment: if someone could provide me some source code or correction to achieve really appreciate it

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?   You should be using bulk insert example here http://sqlserverteam.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-bulk-insert-to-load-text-file.html or reading the file directly from java, put the data into variables and submit it.  Another example here: http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-load-text-or-csv-file-data-into-sql-server.html

Comment: One more response... Similar thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539592/how-to-execute-bulk-insert-statement-in-java-using-jdbc-with-db-sql-server-200  You also need to think about how something like this goes to production.  You file would have to be on the same host as the SQLServer, so if you don't have access to that in production, you might want to look at using something other than bulk load (load in SQL Server used to be used for restoring backups)

Comment: Mike is to make massive loads from a file txt, I missed indicate that.

Comment: Hi Andres, I have tried to clean you your question as best I could. I am a little confused about what it is you are trying to do with your variables and the scanner as these variables are never used anywhere after they are assigned.

Comment: @AndresU.Cartagena You can load the data into a staging table using SSIS and manipulate the data from there.  Java can load in batches as well, it's a little more work, but not hard.  Small sample here with a good explanation of checking the results http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298220/jdbc-batch-insert-exception-handling

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Sample Example to Insert Text File to SQL Server Table as a help.
Can be modified accordingly

```
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopyOptions;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Connection Conexión;
        Conexión = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:sqlserver://SSL2541\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;" +
            "databaseName=namedatabase;user=sa;password=password");

        String tablename = "dbo.filetable";

        try {
            File file = new File("file.txt");
            //The Text File has three columns "ID", "FirstName", "Lastname" separated 
            //by comma as delimiter.

            //The Table (tablename) in SQL Server also has same Number of Columns.

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
            fr.close();



            //try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            try (InputStream inputStream = new 
                 ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) 
            {
                //System.out.println("file to be copied to " + tablename);

                // Column information
                SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord fileRecord = new 
                      SQLServerBulkCSVFileRecord(inputStream, 
                            StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), "\\,", true);

                //Here ,  is delimiter in Test File.

                fileRecord.addColumnMetadata(1, "ID", Types.VARCHAR, 0, 0);
                fileRecord.addColumnMetadata(2, "FirstName", Types.VARCHAR, 0, 0);
                fileRecord.addColumnMetadata(3, "LastName", Types.VARCHAR, 0, 0);

                // Setting bulk insert options(batch size). Insert each 10000 rows in 
                //bulk from N number of rows in Text File.

                SQLServerBulkCopyOptions copyOptions = new SQLServerBulkCopyOptions();
                copyOptions.setBatchSize(10000);

                try (SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy = new 
                          SQLServerBulkCopy(Conexión))
                {
                    bulkCopy.setBulkCopyOptions(copyOptions);
                    bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName(tablename);
                    bulkCopy.writeToServer(fileRecord);
                }

                System.out.println("Data from text file Inserted from Java to 
                                    SQLserver Done");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```